# testing with phpunit

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, phpunit

I'm trying to test my controllers.
I followed this guide:

http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-a ... s/2010/11/

Everything was ok until I wanted to use this call in my test function:
$this->dispatch('/');
I thing the problem is with bootstrapping, but I don't know how to resolve this.
I paste my files involved in the testing:

application.ini = http://pastie.org/2248669

phpunit.xml =

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    <directory>./application</directory>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
    <directory>./library</directory>
</testsuite>

<filter>
    <!-- If Zend Framework is inside your project's library, uncomment this filter -->
    <whitelist>
  <directory suffix=".php">../application</directory>
  <directory suffix=".php">../library/Kolcms</directory>
    <exclude>
      <directory suffix=".php">../library/Zend</directory>
      <directory suffix=".php">../library/Kolcms/Model/DB</directory>
      <directory suffix=".phtml">../library/</directory>
      <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
      <file suffix=".php">../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
    </exclude>
    </whitelist>

</filter>

<logging>
  <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8"
   yui="true" highlight = "true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
</logging>
```

bootstrap.php =

```
   <?php

  // Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
   || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

// Define application environment
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../../Zend'),
   get_include_path()
)));


/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'ControllerTestCase.php';
// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
   APPLICATION_ENV,
   APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap();
clearstatcache();
```

ControllerTestCase.php =

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

class ControllerTestCase
extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

/**
 *
 * @var Zend_Application
 */

protected $application;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootstrap = array($this,'appBootstrap');
    parent::setUp();
}
public function appBootstrap()
{
    $this->application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
            );

$this->application->bootstrap();

}

public function  tearDown()
{
  $this->resetRequest();
  $this->resetResponse();

  parent::tearDown();
}

}
```

indexControllerTest.php =

```
<?php
include_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/core/controllers/IndexController.php';
class Core_IndexControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
      public function testDefaultShouldInvokeAction()
      {
          $this->dispatch('/core/index/index');
          $this->assertController('index');
          $this->assertAction('index');
          $this->assertModule('core');
      }
}
```

And here is my phpunit output:

```
$ phpunit 
PHPUnit 3.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object in  
/home/aykut/dev/kolonicms/application/modules/core/controllers/ErrorController.php on 
line 49

Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object in 
/home/aykut/dev/kolonicms/application/modules/core/controllers/ErrorController.php
on line 49
```

Can somebody help me, please.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you don't have a route for the URL `/core/index/index`, and so ZF is redirecting to your error controller. Next, `ErrorController.php` has a bug that causes it to call the `hasResource()` method on a variable that doesn't hold an object or is `null`. It will probably be easier to diagnose the issue if you fix the error controller first.

This is precisely why I built separate abstract test-case classes for controllers and views. I don't like that Zend's `ControllerTestCase` tests the route, dispatcher, and views in addition to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If we could see the code in the `dispatch()` method, it would be easier, but I can assume that there is probably an error that was triggered somewhere in the `setUp()` (maybe in the bootstrap), swallowing the exception. After that it tried to call `tearDown` and the attributes used in `resetRequest()` (maybe `$this->application` or `$this->bootstrap` where never initialized in setup resulting in a PHP Error.

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478669/phpunit-3-7-19-and-symfony2-broken-tests/33282914#33282914) explaining when this kind or error can occur. I know its an old post, but if it can help someone else.